# Help with a very common problem regarding a Wifi Adapter Driver

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

As the title suggests, I need help with compiling and building a new driver that I need for my Wifi Adapter.

I am aware that this question has no doubt been asked many times and answered, however each device and the drivers associated are different.

The device itself is vital for me in regards to being able to have a solid Internet connection for study, work etc. I am currently living quite a distance from the Wifi Hotspot which provides Internet to our community. This device will extend the signal to the Hotspot allowing me to jump from a connection of 1 bar to 3 bars. Due to manufacturer and the lack of support the drivers that were included on the CD provided with the device are near useless and outdated.

On a side note: I would also like to learn about the details of how to compile and build this type of driver for future reference.

Details are below:

My OS: Ubuntu MATE 1.12.1

Device: Alfa Long Range Duel Band AWUS052NH

Link to Driver (version= Linux:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/hvh48m

Comment: The link does not go anywhere useful.  The page asks for a "verify code".

Comment: Alfa's automatic Captcha response requires a new capture upon every visit, i think.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and include the pertinent info from that web page.  I doubt many people will struggle to get through that web site to answer your question.

Comment: Edit my original question and make reference to the new link containing the drivers that i need help with?..